# How to set up system variables in windows 10 for oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, variables

ORACLE_BASE=C:\oracle; ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE\product\11.2\db_1;

ORACLE_SID=sid_name_here;

PATH=$PATH:ORACLE_HOME\bin; 
Those are the system variables that need to be set up. However, I don't know how to find the sid_name because how can I find the SID name, if I can't query in the connection that I want to access to begin with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I found my sid name. But I still can't connect to the system database in Oracle. What do I need to do next?

Comment: " I still can't connect to the system database " is not very useful to a reader.  Please edit your question, and show relevant errors.

Comment: error ora -01017 (wrong password) when I try to login to the system-xe account of oracle 12c on Windows 10; despite me knowing the password.

Comment: Be aware it is case-sensitive also.  I'm going with Oracle telling you, you have the wrong password despite your assertion.

Comment: i even went about to change it. Now the new error is that the network adaptor cannot establish a connection ora17002.

Comment: On top of that, I can't even enable the oraclexetnslistener in the services.msc.?

Comment: I really wish I could speak to a professional about this!! Someone needs to walk me through this problem. I'm thinking of simply just formatting my computer and installing oracle 12c again. Some say microsoft sql server is interfering with it.

Comment: i'm gonna try using oracle on another computer. If you know why I can't enable the listener tell me!!

Comment: @mitzy If that's fresh install of Oracle I would uninstall it, find some tutorial how to install and run Oracle step by step and follow it. It it quite hard to tell why something is not working without seeing the patient. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `services.msc` (Control Panel/Administrative Tools). 
Sort by description (Oracle ones have no description so go on top). 
Find service `Oracle***TNSListener`. 
This what stands for `***` is your `SID`.

Second way. Go to `ORACLE_HOME\server\network\ADMIN` edit `tnslistener.ora` and read `SID` name there.